# How to create a Telegram Bot Inline Keyboard Menu that doesn't affect everyone?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have created a Python Telegram Bot with an Inline Keyboard multi-level menu.
[image: This type of keyboard buttons]

The idea behind the implementation is so that people can switch between different categories within a restaurant menu (eg. Pasta and Mains) to see the items that are listed under each individual category.

I am using edit_message_text from the Telebot library to edit the message such that the markup returned is the reply markup for the next menu. The issue is that in a group chat, this changes the menu on screen for every user, so effectively only one person can use the bot at the same time.

Is there a way to do it such that I can do this menu system using Inline Keyboard Buttons, without having it change for everyone? I want only the user to see the changes when a menu is switched.

Answer (score 1):

## No

<sup>AFAIK</sup>

Telegram doesn't have this feature, Messages are public in a group, and If you want to achieve what you asked, you should be using Private Chat instead of groups.